# Slicers in Excel 2016 disappear when refresh after data load

Tags: excel, export-to-excel, closedxml, slicers

When we create a excel file, with sample data, we configure slicers with pivot table and charts, and everything works then.

When we include the excel file in our solution, to download the file as part of a "BI Portal", the slicers disappear.

We are using ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook with cell by cell construction with the Export to Excel functionality using NPOI dll

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Pivot-Table-example pivot table support in ClosedXML is still experimental.

Slicers themselves are a novel Excel feature and are not directly supported in ClosedXML either.